Chrome extension with Vite manfest V3 how to listen network calls that is made on the page
i was working on Chrome extension with Vite using typescript am was able to inject a button a page that i wanted know to append the button on that page there is a URL + search/open API call that run in the page which i need to listen in my background Script anyone who tried this kinda thing put some solution.
